# How to set the values base on a class

Tags: java

Not sure whether my title is correct or not. I create a variable based on the datatype of the class. I have listed some of the example as below.

I created 3 classes:

1. testing.java
2. Sentence.java
3. Entity.java

I am new to java and wanted to learn.

Testing.java

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.*;

public class testing {

    private static Entity ent; 


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
      ent.setStart(1);
      ent.setBegin(2);
      Entity entity = ent.setStart(start); # My question is in this part
      List<String> sentences = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("I have a thing", "I have nothing"));
      List<String> context = sentences.subList(0,sentences.size() - 1);
      String target = sentences.get(sentences.size() -1 );

    } 

}
```

Sentence.java

```
package test;

import java.util.List;

public class Sentence {

    private List<Entity> entities;

    public List<Entity> getEntities() {
        return entities;
    }

    public void setEntities(List<Entity> entities) {
        this.entities = entities;
    }

}
```

Entity.java

```
package test;


public class Entity {

    private Integer begin;

    private Integer start;

    public Integer getBegin() {
        return begin;
    }

    public void setBegin(Integer begin) {
        this.begin = begin;
    }

    public Integer getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public void setStart(Integer start) {
        this.start = start;
    }

}
```

I do not understand what to do to create a variable for entity. I have been trying but it wont work.

I also wanted to know why shouldn't I import Entity.java and Sentence.java into Testing.java? I thought we must import it in order to use it? Somehow it worked without the use of import.

Comment: you are doing so by      private static Entity ent; ,      though it is just a reference and need to be initialised.       private static Entity ent = new Entity();        more here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

Comment: they must be in the same package therefore you are not able to import them

Comment: Thank you guys, I figured it out now. Will keep improving. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also wanted to know why shouldnt I import Entity.java and Sentence.java into Testing.java? I thought we must import it in order to use it?

You only have to import stuff that is in a different package. Your stuff is all in package called `test` so you don't need to import it.

About the problem itself. You are probably getting a `NullPointerException` because you are not initializing your static variable `ent`

In the first line of your `main` method, you should initialize it like so:
`ent = new Entity();`

Also this part does not make any sense at all:
`Entity entity = ent.setStart(start);`

`ent.setStart(start)` returns void not an `Entity`.

So to conclude, something like this should be at least compilable:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
      ent = new Entity();
      ent.setStart(1);
      ent.setBegin(2);
      int start = 0;
      ent.setStart(start);
      List<String> sentences = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("I have a thing", "I have nothing"));
      List<String> context = sentences.subList(0,sentences.size() - 1);
      String target = sentences.get(sentences.size() -1 );

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much and now I understand but may i know why we need to ent.setStart 2 times?

Comment: You dont :) I did not fix you logic, I just made it compilable :). If that answered you question then please consider marking it as an accepted answer :)

Comment: Yes, you answered it but I have to wait for 1 more minute to mark it as answer.